# Magnification of high intensities using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image which has areas of high intensities and I would like to magnify those intensities. I accomplished this in `Matlab` by converting a integer array in `(0,255)` to floating point from `(0,1)`, then squaring each value and finally multiplying by `255` and converting back to integer.

How would something like this be done in `openCV`? Is there a way to access the elements piece by piece? Even so, I suppose this would be inefficient and wonder if there are `openCV` methods which are vectorized or otherwise optimized to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input grayscale image:

[image]

the result of your algorithm is:

[image]

You can:

- convert and scale with `convertTo`.
- square each pixel with element-wise multiplication `mul`, or use `pow` to raise to an arbitrary number.

This is the simple code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    imshow("Original", img);

    // converting to float in (0,1)
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);
    // power with an arbitrary number. Use 2 to square
    pow(img, 2, img);
    // multiplying by 255 and back to integer
    img.convertTo(img, CV_8U, 255.0);

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So 'mul' squares it? I was also hoping to raise it to an arbitrary real number (1.9, 1.1, etc). Is that possible?

Comment: Updated, Just use `pow`